# Calculate side AD of tetrahedron, given its volume, angle ACB and 2AD+AC+BC=18

Tags: vectors

The question says

> The volume of a tetrahedron $DABC$ is $9$ cubic units. If $\angle ACB =\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $2AD + AC + BC = 18$, then the length $AD$ is

What I could come up with

If I set up a coordinate system with $D$ at origin, and other points with their respective vectors
$$9=\frac{1}{6} \big( \vec {a} \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c ) \big)$$
To solve for $AD$, solving for $AC + BC $ suffices. Cosine rule combined with dot products only leads me to
$$(AC +BC)^2 = AB^2 + (2+ \sqrt{3}) AC \cdot BC = \left| \vec b - \vec a \right|^2 + \frac{(4+2\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}} \left( (\vec c - \vec a ) \cdot (\vec c - \vec b ) \right) $$
I dont see how this connected to the scalar triple product, nor do I know if this is the correct start/approach to this problem. Can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h$ denote the length of perpendicular from point $D$ onto the plane passing through points $A, B$ and $C$. Using the formula for volume of tetrahedron and application of AM-GM inequality in the following steps
$$9=\frac{1}{3} \left[ \triangle ABC \right] \times h = \frac{h}{12} AC \times BC$$
$$\implies h \times AC \times BC =108 \leq h \left( \frac{AC + BC}{2} \right) ^2 = h \left( 9 -AD \right)^2 $$
Since,
$$27 = \frac{h}{4} \left( 9 - AD \right)^2 \le \frac{h}{4} \left( 9-h \right)^2 \leq \left( \frac{h + \tfrac{9-h}{2} + \tfrac{9-h}{2}}{3} \right)^3 =27 $$
Since, equality holds when $$\frac{9-h}{2} = h \implies h=3 \implies AD= 3 \text{ units} \qquad \square $$